# Want to create staging subdomain e.g staging.example.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain, server-administration

I have e.g www.example.com as my website domain, and now as testing instance I want to add www.staging.example.com. How this can be achieved.  I tried searching for solutions on google, but got confused. Any suggestions on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line of attack would be to create a new DNS record for the domain you want. This can usually be done from the control panel provided by the service/company you purchased the domain through.

If your staging server is hosted and available at the ip A.B.C.D for example, you'd create a new A record for www.staging that points to A.B.C.D

Once this is done, you'll want to add a new (v)host entry on your server that's housing the staging site (this differs whether you're using Apache, NGINX etc). A simple Google search on how to do this should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I know it can be done from cpanel, do u know how to do it through ssh.

Comment: Hello. Server-side decision is at nginx config for your virtual host. Something like `server_name www.staging.example.com` at `server` block, and linked to your application server upstream. But anyway you should configure your DNS settings for domain(s).